# EAS build for Android failing - Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I recently switched to EAS from expo build and while i was able to create a build successfully for IOS, I have been struggling to make a build for Android, here is the error message I am getting if anyone could decipher the problem.

```
 Error: [stderr] Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * What went wrong:\n
[stderr] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:collectReleaseDependencies'.
[stderr] 
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
[stderr]  > Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push.
[stderr] Required by:
[stderr] project :app
[stderr] > No matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release' but:
[stderr] - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

and this is my eas.js config file

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.8.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium"
      }
    },
    "production": {
      "ios": {
        "resourceClass": "m-medium",
        "image": "macos-monterey-12.1-xcode-13.2"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```